# line equidistant from two sets in the plane

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-topology

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of the plane, both closed, nonempty, and connected.  Define $E(A, B)$ as the set of points in the plane equidistant from $A$ and $B$.  For example, if $A$ is a point and $B$ is a straight line, $E$ is a parabola.

**(1)** I think that $E$ is always homeomorphic to a circle or a line.  Is that right?

**(2)** Are there any generalizations?  For example, if instead of the plane we take the ambient space to be any $n$-manifold with a metric, is $E$ something like an $(n - 1)$-dimensional CW complex?

And here are some bonus questions...

Are there conditions on $A$ and $B$ which will guarantee that $E$ is a submanifold of codimension 1?  For example, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $E$ is not always a surface even if $A$ and $B$ are connected.  (To see this, let $A$ and $B$ be like two forks kissing: for example, $A$ is the union of the three line segments given by the sequence $(-1, 0, 0)$, $(-1, 0, 4)$, $(1, 0, 4)$, $(1, 0, 0)$, and $B$ is given similarly by $(0, 1, 4)$, $(0, 1, 0)$, $(0, -1, 0)$, $(0, -1, 4)$.)  But perhaps $E$ is a surface if $A$ and $B$ are separated by a hyperplane.

What do we get in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $A$ and $B$ are finite?

I think I can prove that if $A$ and $B$ are graphs of continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , then $E$ is too.  Is there a similar result for $C^k$ functions?  Is there a nice description of the $E$ function if the $A$ and $B$ functions are, say, polynomials?

Comment: Gosh...not even the ghost of an answer.  Do I really need to put a bounty on this one?  Surely someone knows something.

Comment: I think you want to think of $E$ as the zero level set of $e(x) = d(x,A) - d(x,B)$. Then I imagine you might able to prove that the sets $\{x: e(x) < 0\}$ and $\{x: e(x) > 0\}$ are connected, from which nice things should follow.

Comment: I have to say I don't understand your example in $\mathbb R^3$. When $i=1$, $A_1 = e^{2\pi/4} \not\in S^1$. Perhaps you meant $A_k = e^{2\pi ik/4}$ instead? And how do the four points $A_0A_0'A_2A_2'$ (which I presume are $(1,0,0)$, $(1,0,4)$, $(-1,0,0)$, $(-1,0,4)$ in $\mathbb R^3$) specify a line?

Comment: Thanks @RahulNarain, I fixed up that example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of these references answers exactly your question, but each addresses special cases of your question.  If nothing else, it gives you the vocabulary to search further:  the key term is *bisector*:

- "Bisectors  of Linearly Separable Sets."
  Lee  R.  Nackman  and  Vijay  Srinivasan.
  *Discrete Comput Geom* 6:263-275 (1991).
  ([Springer link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02574688)).
- "The Bisector of a Point and a Plane Algebraic Curve."
  Huahao Shou, Tao Li and Yongwei Miao.
  Communications in Computer and Information Science, 2011, Volume 164, 449-455, 2011.
  ([Springer link](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-24999-0_62)).
- "Bisector Curves of Planar Rational Curves."
  Gershon Elber, Myung-soo Kim.
  1999.
  ([Citeseer link](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.39.9496)).

Below is Fig. 6(a) from the 3rd paper above:
[image: Fig.6a]

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the closed segment from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$ plus the closed segment from $(0,0$) to $(0,-1)$ and $B$ the closed segment from $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$  plus the closed segment from $(1,0)$ to $(2,0)$. I think the equidistant set is homeomorphic to a sans-serif Y.

Comment: I think the equidistant set is the line $x=1/2$ here. If $y<0$, the points on $A$ and $B$ closest to $(x,y)$ are $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ respectively, and similarly when $y>1$.

Comment: @RahulNarain: you are right for the previous version.  It was too simple.  Try this one...

Comment: I don't think that works either. Can you draw a picture? Also: if the points to the left of the Y are closer to $A$, and the ones to the right are closer to $B$, what about the points above the fork of the Y?

Comment: @RahulNarain: You are right.  I was trying to get a hyperbola from the end points, but it doesn't work.