# What is a function that is equidistant from two functions?

Tags: functions, euclidean-geometry

For example, let $f(x)$ be $x^2$ and $g(x)$ be $x^3 + 1$. It is easy to see that $h(x)=\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{2}$ is not equidistant from $f$ and $g$.

Then, what is a general form of a fucntion $h(x)$ that has the same distance between both of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ ?

*If it is hard to define $h(x)$ over all range of $x$, limiting a range of $x$ is possible.

Comment: Which metric are you using?

Comment: Maybe _Euclidian_. The motivation of my question is 'drawing a cetered line of a road/path'

Comment: The Euclidean metric is defined on the reals not on the functions.

Comment: Well. I mean to draw 2 lines from $(x, h(x))$ to the $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and each line is perpendicular to $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively. Thus, intersections are $(x_f, f(x_f))$ and $(x_g, g(x_g))$ and $x_f$ may differ $x_g$. I want to get a function $h(x)$ such that $||(x, h(x))-(x_f, f(x_f))||$ = $||(x, h(x))-(x_g, g(x_g))||$ for all $x$ in a given range

Comment: I think you want to say that each point of the graph of $h$ is equidistant from the graphs of $f$ and $g$.  I raised this question in [line equidistant from two sets in the plane](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209662/line-equidistant-from-two-sets-in-the-plane), which was never answered, but there is an interesting paper there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Wolff. I've found that question a minutes ago. :)

Comment: "Perpendicular" might not make sense if $f$ or $g$ isn't differentiable. If they are, then I think your sense of equidistant is equivalent to the one in the linked question above.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a circle moving so that it is simultaneously tangent to your two curves. Then the locus of the center of this circle would be the "equidistant" curve that you want. In computational geometry, this curve is called the "medial axis", and it has a great many uses. If you want to learn about it, you can get started at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis). The page includes a link to code that computes the medial axis. If your curves are very simple (straight lines and circular arcs, for example), there are closed-form solutions. In more general cases, the best you can do is a polygonal approximation.

Answer (score -1):

It would be: $$y=-\frac{1}{g'\left(x\right)}\left(\frac{\left(f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right)}{\left(-\frac{1}{g'\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{f'\left(x\right)}\right)}\right)+g\left(x\right)$$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference